# How To Create Chart Series Array Objects in Asp.Net Charts C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to create series dynamically for that  i created series array objects like this

```
        Series[] series = new Series[10];

        series[0].Name = "Result Chart";
```

but while execution of program it showing object reference null error
  how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

```
Series[] series = new Series[10];
series[0] = new Series();// this line is the one you missed
series[0].Name = "Result Chart";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Series[] series = new Series[10];
```

This line create an array. The new is just for creating array of series.

This line puts the value at the 0th index

```
series[0].Name = "Result Chart";
```

The problem is that you have not instantiated the object at 0th index.
So you need to instantiated every index which you want to use.
Like if you want to use the 0th index then you will have to use

```
series[0] = new Series();
```

or just create a loop to instantiated every index as follows

```
for(int i=0;i<series.Count;i++)
{
   series[i] = new Series();
}
```